# LUIS Error when publishing. "publish your application first before attempting to package it"

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

When trying to publish, after train and test, I get the following message

*"Bad argument, the specified application has not been published yet. Please publish your application first before attempting to package it"*

This error occurs after cloning my first version "control your application versions...". If I set my cloned version as active, work on it, train and then try to publish it I get the error.

If I turn active the initial (original) version, and train and publish then all works as expected.

Already tried having one version in End point slot Production and the cloned in staging.

LUIS still works under the previously published version.

Comment: Got the same problem: the error is thrown but your model is still trained

Comment: trained ok, but can you confirm that the published version is the one you expected to be?. Meanwhile, I will do a major modification in my cloned version so to check if actually gets published. Thanks! @Nicolas

Comment: Good question sorry I took a shortcut (was having the problem during training, not publishing).